# Modified and re-signed app doesn't retrieve file names

Tags: android, livecode, jarsigner, apktool

I have "updated" an old Mac to Mac OS X 10.7.5. I have installed JDK 1.7.0_72 on this Mac. I'm trying use a LiveCode standalone application on my old Android tablet with Android version 2.3.3.

The unmodified standalone, built with the option "sign for development only" runs fine on my tablet, but video won't display.

First, I built the app for Android, using LiveCode 6.6.2 for Windows. Then I copied it over to my Mac. I used

```
$ java -jar apktool.jar decode /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/User/Desktop/apk\ tool/MyApp.apk app
```

to decompile the apk file. It appeared in a folder with the name "app" in my Home directory, with subdirectories:

```
app
    AndroidManifest.xml
    apktool.yml
    assets/
        doc/
        links.txt
        pic/
        vid/
            Demos/
            Examples/
            Other/
                Simple Animation.mp4
                Vimeo Pro Example.html
            Tutorials/
                SQL.html
    build/
    lib/
    res/
    smali/
```

The contents of the assets folder is included by LiveCode's standalone builder. I created all of these files and folders during project development. The folders in the `vid` folder contain several HTML files and one mp4 file. I have listed only a few of the html files in the file tree.

I changed the file AndroidManifest.xml by replacing the line

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:debuggable="false">
```

with

```
<application android:label="MyApp" android:debuggable="false" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
```

After this, I rebuilt the app, using apktool again. I used `sudo`, because [here](http://quality.runrev.com/show_bug.cgi?id=10267) it said I had to use sudo:

```
$ sudo java -jar /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/User/Desktop/apk\ tool/apktool_1.5.2.jar b -a /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Developer/android-s-d-k-mac_x86/platform-tools/aapt
```

It appears that if you use sudo once, you have to use sudo all the time. So, now I had to sign it using

```
$ sudo jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHAwithRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/User/app/dist/MyApp.apk myalias
```

I verified that it was signed and changed the name of the file then aligned the file

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/User/app/dist/MyApp.apk
```

to

```
/Volumes/Macintosh HD/Users/User/app/dist/MyApp_unaligned.apk
```

I aligned the file using

```
$ zipalign -v 4 /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/User/app/dist/MyApp_unaligned.apk /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/Users/user/app/dist/MyApp.apk
```

This file should work on my Android tablet. I'm able to start and run the file, but my app doesn't see any of the files in the sub folders of folder `vid/`, except for `Simple Animation.mp4`. However, it *does* notice that there are files. A repeat loop that checks all folders in folder `vid/` for files creates a list, but the lines in the list are empty, one line for each file, meaning that it can't figure out what the names of the files are. Needless to say, I checked that all files are included in the new apk file.

What may cause this?

If you wonder about the file paths: I started my Mac from an external disk and used the files on the internal disk. So, /Volumes/Macintosh HD isn't the system disk here.

Comment: Do you use specialFolderPath("engine")?

Comment: Actually, yes I believe I do, but mind that this question is over half a year old already. Also notice that the `put the files` returns a line for every file, which means that somehow the files are seen, but not their names.